# Как вывести под каждое значение результат

Tags: php, mysql

Есть подарочные карты,которые покупаются за внутресайтовую валюту(монеты)есть 3 карты и нужно сделать,чтобы под каждую карту выдавалось определенное кол-во монет($prize),а не рандомно под все сразу(как сейчас)

```
include 'bd.php';
$login = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['login']);
$query = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login'"));  
$money = intval($query['money']);
$type = intval($_POST['cardType']);
// ---------------ЦЕНЫ------------------
$prices = array(
    0 => 130,
    1 => 180,
    2 => 250
);
// -------------------------------------
$cardPrice = $prices[$type-1];
if ($money < $cardPrice) 
    exit("alert(\"Недостаточно монет!\");");


// ------------ПОКУПКА------------------    


$chars = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K',
    'L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
$serial = '';
$max = count($chars)-1;
for($i=0;$i<20;$i++)
    $serial .= (!($i % 5) && $i ? '-' : '').$chars[rand(0, $max)]; // Генерация серии
$cvv = rand(0,99) . "-" . rand(100,999);
$until = strtotime("+7 days");
$money = $money - $cardPrice;
$prize = rand(50,450) . ":" . rand(500,2000);
$cardNames = array(
    0 => 'Primitive',
    1 => 'Standart',
    2 => 'Premium Gold' 

);
$cardName = $cardNames[$type-1];
// -------------MYSQL-------------------
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `money` = '$money' WHERE `login` = '$login'") or die("alert(\"Ошибка\");");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `bonus` (`serial`,`cvv`,`id`,`until`,`prize`) VALUES('$serial','$cvv',NULL,'$until','$prize')");
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `chat` (`login`,`text`,`group`,`id`) VALUES('sys','Пользователь  <font color=\"yellow\">$login</font> купил подарочную карту <font color=\"red\">$cardName</font>.','0',NULL)");
exit("$.facebox({ajax: 'bonus/?serial=$serial&cvv=$cvv'});");

?>
```

Comment: А как надо? Заменить `$prize = rand(50,450) . ":" . rand(500,2000);` на свое не вариант? На `$prize = 555`, к примеру?

Comment: Там 3 карты
0 => 'Primitive',
    1 => 'Standart',
    2 => 'Premium Gold' 
Нужно,чтобы под каждую было разное значение
Например:
$prize_primitive = 100
$prize_standart = 250
$prize_premium_gold = 500
Это неправильно,но на подобие такого должно что-то быть

Comment: Ну так создайте аналог `$prices` и так же обращайтесь к нему по индексу?!

Comment: Можете дать пример ??Не совсем понял,как это прописать ?

Comment: Оформил ввиде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Добавляем массив `bonuses` по аналогии массива `prices` и обращаемся к нему по той же схеме:

```
$bonuses = array(
    0 => 100,
    1 => 250,
    2 => 500
);

$prize = $bonuses[$type-1];
```

Полный пример, с вашего кода:

```
include 'bd.php';
$login = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['login']);
$query = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login'"));  
$money = intval($query['money']);
$type = intval($_POST['cardType']);
// ---------------ЦЕНЫ------------------
$prices = array(
    0 => 130,
    1 => 180,
    2 => 250
);
$bonuses = array(
    0 => 100,
    1 => 250,
    2 => 500
);
// -------------------------------------
$cardPrice = $prices[$type-1];
if ($money < $cardPrice) 
    exit("alert(\"Недостаточно монет!\");");


// ------------ПОКУПКА------------------    


$chars = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K',
    'L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
$serial = '';
$max = count($chars)-1;
for($i=0;$i<20;$i++)
    $serial .= (!($i % 5) && $i ? '-' : '').$chars[rand(0, $max)]; // Генерация серии
$cvv = rand(0,99) . "-" . rand(100,999);
$until = strtotime("+7 days");
$money = $money - $cardPrice;

$prize = $bonuses[$type-1];

$cardNames = array(
    0 => 'Primitive',
    1 => 'Standart',
    2 => 'Premium Gold' 

);
$cardName = $cardNames[$type-1];
// -------------MYSQL-------------------
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `money` = '$money' WHERE `login` = '$login'") or die("alert(\"Ошибка\");");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `bonus` (`serial`,`cvv`,`id`,`until`,`prize`) VALUES('$serial','$cvv',NULL,'$until','$prize')");
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `chat` (`login`,`text`,`group`,`id`) VALUES('sys','Пользователь  <font color=\"yellow\">$login</font> купил подарочную карту <font color=\"red\">$cardName</font>.','0',NULL)");
exit("$.facebox({ajax: 'bonus/?serial=$serial&cvv=$cvv'});");
/// ЗАКРЫВАЮЩИЙ ТЭГ СТАВИТЬ НЕ НУЖНО
```